# Flask ローカルサーバーで処理できて、wsgiで処理できない

Tags: python, python3, flask

現在Flaskでアプリケーションを作成しているのですが、現在POSTした情報をJSONファイルに放り込んでいるのですが、ローカルサーバーを立ち上げて上記処理を実行すると、正常に処理が可能。
公開しているwsgiサーバーでPOSTしてJSONファイルに書き込む箇所でInternal Server Error
が出力されてしまいます。
エラーが出てしまっている箇所はファイルに書き込む処理のところなのですが、通常ローカルサーバーで成功していて、wsgiサーバーで失敗するという状況はあり得るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

自分がやる失敗としては、ファイルシステムへの権限不足があります。
ローカルでやるときのユーザーは自分ですが、公開用のサーバはそれ専用のユーザーとするので。
あと、特定のディレクトリを指すはずのファイルパスが環境変数の設定漏れであらぬ方向を指していたり。